Unmet Dependencies Issues with Local JFrog Debian Artifactory
I have installed JFrog on Ubuntu with a trial license and set up Artifactory for Debian packages. After completing the setup, I uploaded all the dependent Debian packages required for my custom Debian package. All the Debian packages were successfully updated under bionic/core.
On the client machine, I added the repository details to the sources.list. However, when I attempt to install a custom Debian package, I encounter unmet dependency issues, even though I can see that the dependent packages are present in the repository. I have already attempted to resolve this by indexing from the JFrog UI, clicking on "Recalculate Index," but the issues persist.
Furthermore, I observed that when attempting to install the same package on another client machine, I encounter unmet dependencies with a different set of packages. Your assistance in resolving these issues would be greatly appreciated.

Please keep in mind that Ubuntu 18.04 is pretty outdated
